# Objective c add string object to an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays, ipad

I've looked everywhere for this, online, on stack overflow and cannot still work out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to add an element to an existing NSMutableArray. But it crashes on line 4:

```
-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x897b320
```

The code:

```
NSMutableArray *mystr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

mystr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello",@"world",@"etc",nil];

NSString *obj = @"hiagain";

[mystr addObject:obj];
```

What am I doing wrong? This is driving me crazy!!!

Comment: Why the downvotes? - it seems a reasonable question to me , just because someone does not know the NS API, doesent make it a bad question

Comment: @gheese I don't get it either. It's a clear question. It provides the specific code and a specific error message. Downvoting without a reason shouldn't be allowed. It helps no one. I think it's just some grumpy guys that think just because they know this stuff, they should downvote what appears to be a silly question to them.

Comment: I'm not one of the down-voters, but I would suggest the downvotes are because : 1. There has seemingly been no effort to look up the error message (unrecognized selector). 2. If the error message had been looked up, it should have led to believe that the NSArray does not respond to that selector. This would have led to 3. to look up the NSArray documentation which would reveal that it has no such selector.

Comment: @Nick Bull - agreed, but one must remember that for newbies "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x897b320" wouldn't mean a thing.  Also I suspect that 50 % of the questions posted here wouldnt meet all the criteria you state

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You array is not mutable!. Use `NSMutableArray`

```
mystr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello",@"world",@"etc",nil];
```

You get  **unrecognized selector** since `NSArray` does not contain the **addObject** method

Comment: @Imme22009 When you do this, you don't need the call to `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` on the first line.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be:

```
NSMutableArray *mystr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"hello",@"world",@"etc",nil];

NSString *obj = @"hiagain";

[mystr addObject:obj];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhhh spotted it already

Line 2 should be:

```
[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello",@"world",@"etc",nil];
```

Sorry to waste your time with that!

Comment: I think you mean NSMutableArray!

Answer (score 0):

The second line you're reassigning an instance of `NSArray` rather of `NSMutableArray` to your `mystr` variable.

Try something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *mystr = [NSMutableArray  arrayWithObjects:@"hello",@"world",@"etc",nil];

[mystr addObject:@"hiagain"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You originally create mystr as a mutable array, but then assign it to a standard NSArray in the next line.  Instead of calling "arrayWithObjects," add each item using "addObjects" or some other function that doesn't create a new immutable array.